# Get notified when an item runs out of stock in MWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

If I'm listing multiple items with different quantities, is there a way to get notified when I run out of stock for any of them?
Of course if there is a report that can return the currently out of stock items then that would be great too.

I'm using the MFN (Merchant Fulfillment Network) and there are millions of items currently listed on Amazon.

What I have tried:

1. The Reports API has the [inventory report](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_ES/reports/Reports_ReportType.html#ReportTypeCategories__ListingsReports) which returns all stock, but it can be requested only once per day (since we have a catalogue of millions of books) and it takes about 5 hours to be generated.
2. The [fulfilment API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_ES/fba_inventory/FBAInventory_ListInventorySupply.html) has a function `ListInventorySupply`, but it works only for AFN (Amazon fulfilment network) so it work only for fulfilment by Amazon sellers.

Answer (score 0):

We use the Reports API by scheduling our inventory report every hour.  I have a process that retrieves the generated file to our server, which then reads the file and processes it in our systems.  It sounds like you've been down this road already.  I'm not aware of the once per day limitation unless it's because you have such a large catalog.  We have around 50000 SKUs with about 5000 of those at FBA and have no problem requesting a report manually or via the Reports API every hour.  When we request manually, it usually takes a minute or two.

The MWS team is ready to help, you just have to fill out the contact us form [here](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/mws/contactus.html)

I was at a meeting in Detroit with the team a couple weeks ago and they asked us to contact them anytime they need help with their solutions.  Great team of folks.

Comment: Thanks Scott, but according to this [amazon help page](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200203320) in the inventory report section: _ If you have more than 500,000 listings, do not request more than one Inventory Report per day._ we exceeded the limt long time ago :)

Comment: Contact the MWS team.  They told me that they can help you get around limitations like this and offer suggestions.